# io.SectionReaderで、Readできる残バイトがあるかどうかを確認する方法

Tags: go

任意のファイルを指定したサイズに分割しようと、以下のように書きました。
（エラー処理は省略しています）

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    src := "inputfile"

    in, _ := os.Open(src)
    defer in.Close()

    // 分割後ファイルのサイズ
    const size = 2

    var offset int64 = 0
    cnt := 1

    for {
        r := io.NewSectionReader(in, offset, size)

        out, _ := os.Create(src + "_" + strconv.Itoa(cnt))
        defer out.Close()

        n, _ := io.Copy(out, r)

        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        offset += size
        cnt += 1
    }
}
```

実行すると、以下のように分割はできたのですが、ゼロバイトの余計なファイルが作られてしまいました。原因は分割後のファイルを`os.Create`してから中身を書き込んでいるためです。

```
2018/08/08  15:16                 7 inputfile
2018/08/08  16:09                 2 inputfile_1
2018/08/08  16:09                 2 inputfile_2
2018/08/08  16:09                 2 inputfile_3
2018/08/08  16:09                 1 inputfile_4
2018/08/08  16:09                 0 inputfile_5
```

そこで、事前に分割前のファイルサイズを調べておいてからそのサイズを使ってループを抜ける、という方法も考えたのですが、別の方法として、`SectionReader`を作った時点でReadできる残バイトがあるかどうかを確認すればよいと思い、以下のような判定を追加しました。

```
for {
    r := io.NewSectionReader(in, offset, size)

    // 読み込めるバイトが残っているか確認する
    buf := make([]byte, 1)
    bn, _ := r.Read(buf)
    if bn == 0 {
        break
    }
    // ファイルポインタを先頭に戻す
    r.Seek(0, 0)
```

これで一応は達成できたのですが、そもそも「Readできる残バイトがあるかどうか」を知る一般的？な方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufio.Peek()` を使ってみるのはどうでしょうか。

```golang
for {
    r := bufio.NewReader(io.NewSectionReader(in, offset, size))
    if _, err := r.Peek(1); err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    out, _ := os.Create(src + "_" + strconv.Itoa(cnt))
    defer out.Close()

    io.Copy(out, r)

    offset += size
    cnt += 1
}
```